# Can Mathemetica solve 625 coupled Linear differential Equations?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, wolframalpha

I am trying to solve some physics problem in which i need to solve 625 linear coupled differential equations. I am using the command DSolve for solving them. When i used the same procedure for 25 equations it is working well.

Only difference is, in 25 equations there are no other parameters all coefficients are numerical values. but in case of 625 equations there are some 7 parameters in symbolic form like delta, omega .etc.. ( i think it doesn't matter )

Can Mathemetica solve them ? what is the limiting factor in using the DSolve command ?  If not "DSolve" what could be the other command which can give me the output ?. I tried very hard to get to this 625 equations now if i have to go for some other software it will be very very tough for me...

Comment: Why is this tagged Matlab if the question is about Mathematica? [Mathematica has a dedicated StackExchange site](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com). I recommend that you delete this and ask there. However, you should also improve your question by making it more specific. Actual code and any error messages will help.

Comment: To prevent confusion: Though there is a mathematica site, that does not mean you cannot ask programming questions about mathematica here. However, currently this is not a proper programming question. As such it is not in scope and I vote to close. I would agree you should try probably the mathematica site, but make sure to check what kind of questions are on topic there before formulating your question.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. i will be more specific clear with the question.